# Change UIScrollView contentSize with animation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to change a `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` with an animation so the size decreases / increases on a certain period, something like

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
   scrollView.contentSize.width -= 100.0
}
```

Doesn't work. I don't know if there's a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `transitionWithView` method:

```
      float newHeight = scroller.contentSize.height - someChangeFloat;
      [UIView transitionWithView:scroller
                          duration:0.3f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                        animations:^{
                            scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, newHeight);
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        }];
```